# Ionic 5 firebasex native plugin phone verification signin works but angularfire shows user as null

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, angularfire2, ionic5

I am using Ionic 5 firebaseX native plugin and firebase for phone authentication, I am getting the otp and user is registering in the firebase authentication console, to save additional userdata after signup and using angularfire, but the current user is null in angularfire while it is available using `this.firebaseX.getCurrentUser();`. How can I propagate the firebase instance to the web layer from native layer?

Tried signing in the user in web layer using the idToken from the native layer but it does not worked.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its not the solution but more explanation by the author of the plugin, for anyone who might face this issue https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex/issues/435